# How to write gradient descent code for neural networks in matlab?

Tags: matlab, neural-network, gradient-descent

I'm trying to implement "Stochastic gradient descent" in MATLAB. I followed the algorithm exactly but I'm getting a VERY VERY large w (coffients) for the prediction/fitting function. Do I have a mistake in the algorithm ?

I am trying to write gradient descent for my neural network.

I have my  final network's out put as (net2) and wanted out put as (d) i put this 2 parameters in formula: E=0.5*(d^2-net2) and i got E.

So my problem is that how i can use E? and how can i write my cod in matlab? and how can i update my weights as W?
Pls help me. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at that implementation:

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22010-a-very-simple-and-intuitive-neural-network-implementation